# Monotouch - [NSConcreteValue doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

This seems like a somewhat vague question - but tapping around in my UI I am getting a 'Unrecognized selector sent to instance '. The stack trace is really not very helpful. In general - what is the best way to debug this in Monodevelop? Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: I found a couple of possible solutions here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773628/iphone-debugging-a-crash-when-you-cant-find-it/8729649#8729649  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804404/sigabrt-message-only-with-ios5/7804426#7804426

Comment: The stack trace might not look useful to most people (when you see it it's because a lot of things/checks failed( but it can be **very** useful to some people. Please edit your question to show us both the related code and the stack trace you have. Using those we should be able to find what's wrong.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rolf's link revealed the correct answer.
Changed:

```
CABasicAnimation scale_animation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("transform.scale");
```

to:

```
CABasicAnimation scale_animation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("transform");
```

Thanks!

Comment: simple and perfect :D.

Comment: For me it was "transform.translation.x" to "transform"

Comment: @xindong's answer answers this question better by demonstrating what is causing the crash.

Comment: While this fixed the crash, it just removed my animation altogether.

Answer (score 8):

The first answer is not a good solution. The transform.scale should be a double type, if you assign `fromValue` or `toValue` of CABasicAnimation a NSValue type, it cann't convert to double value, and so App crashed.

Wrong example:

```
     animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5)];
     animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(1.2, 1.2)];
```

Right example:

```
     animation.fromValue = @(0.5);
     animation.toValue = @(1.2);
```